# MySQL - Most efficient way to lookup subclass attributes by parent?

Tags: mysql, join, subclass

I'm trying to implement a subclass pattern in MySQL as outlined here:

http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php

According to the above article, it isn't necessary to have a foreign keys for the parent table.  ("Notice that there is no attribute in the parent table to tell us if a student is a TA, an RA, or neither—the union of two outer join queries will produce a table with all of the information that we need")

Is this really the best pattern?

In my project, I'm trying to implement complete, disjoint specialization for records in my parent table.  For example, I have an "Employees" table, and then various subclass tables -- e.g., "Accountants", "Programmers", and "Lawyers".  Every employee has one and only one subclass, and all subclasses are employees.

For any given employee_id, I want to be able to display all the attributes for that record, including attributes specific to the employee's subclass.  Is joining all the subclass tables (as the article suggests) the most efficient way to do so?  Even if I have potentially hundreds of subclass tables and/or large numbers of parent records?

One alternative I can think of is creating a "subclass_type" column in my "Employees" table.  That way, I could perform a direct lookup on the appropriate subclass table.  Would this be potentially faster than joining lots of separate tables?

Comment: Can you specify what do you want to achieve? Do you need all the subcategories in a single query, or do you need all the subcategories in separate queries? Also, how much do your subcategory tables differ from each-other?

Comment: For any single query of my Employee table, I want to also include the subclass attributes for that employee.For example, "Tom" and "Jane" are records in my employees table.  They each have attributes that are common to all employees (e.g., "name", "age").  Tom is a member of the "Lawyer" subclass, and has attributes specific to the Lawyers table (e.g. "bar_admission_date").  Jane is a member of the "Programmer" subclass, and has attributes specific to that table (e.g., "languages").  So each subclass table has fairly different attributes.

Comment: As an update, I've been told that a NoSQL database might more be useful for what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich,

I believe that in your situation I would either follow your alternative suggestion, or flatten  into one table.

Regarding your alternative suggestion: `employees` gets, say, subclass_type and subclass_id (disallow NULL on each), and no other foreign keys on `accountants`, etc.

Regarding flattening: if the number of subclasses is quite small, you might instead consider fields on `employees` like `accountant_cpa_id` and `lawyer_independent_practice` (boolean). You'd likely validate in the application layer, that only one subclass' `employees` fields ought to be populated for any given row. I would advise against a `subclass_type` field with this tactic, as provides a denormalization headache without commensurate gains.

Hope this helps!